# Wordpress: How to add publish/draft button in Admin Post Lists

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I try to add publish/draft button in Wordpress Admin Post Lists but it doesn’t work well in a certain situation.

### Does Not Work

New post -> Save as Draft -> Publish using new button in Adomin Post Lists

### Does Work

New post -> Publish -> Draft -> Publish using new button in Adomin Post Lists

Thank You all in advance for help or any other ways :D

> Reference :
>   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17794/publish-pending-article-from-front-end-with-a-button
>   (this doesnt work)

Here’s functions.php code

```
    function show_publish_button($post_id){
    $pub_form = <<<EOF
            <form name="make_it_publish" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="{$post_id}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="mi_publish" id="mi_publish" value="mi_publish">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="publish">
             </form>
    EOF;
    echo $pub_form;
    }

    function show_draft_button($post_id){
    $pri_form = <<<EOF
            <form name="make_it_draft" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="{$post_id}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="mi_draft" id="mi_draft" value="mi_draft">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="draft">
             </form>
    EOF;
    echo $pri_form;
    }

    function change_post_status($post_id,$status){

        $time = current_time('mysql');
        wp_update_post(
            array(
               'ID'                         =>  $post_id,
               'post_status'        =>  $status,
               'post_name'          =>  $post_id,
               'post_date_gmt'  =>  get_gmt_from_date( $time )
            )
        );
    }

    add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
        if (isset($_POST['mi_publish']) && $_POST['mi_publish'] == 'mi_publish'){
            if (isset($_POST['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])){
                change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid'],'publish');
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['mi_draft']) && $_POST['mi_draft'] == 'mi_draft'){
            if (isset($_POST['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])){
                change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid'],'draft');
            }
        }
    });


    function manage_posts_columns($columns) {
        $columns['publish'] = "publish";
        $columns['draft'] = "draft";
        return $columns;
    }

    function add_column($column_name, $post_id) {

        if($column_name == 'publish'){
            $pub = "publish";
        }
        if($column_name == 'draft'){
            $pri = "draft";
        }


        if ( isset($pub) && $pub ){
            show_publish_button($post_id);
        } else if ( isset($pri) && $pri ){
            show_draft_button($post_id);
        } else {
            echo __('None');
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'manage_posts_columns' );
    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_column', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is **nest** form tag.

Admin Post Lists is huge form and I added form tag. That's why it didn't work.

Simple way is using ajax and wp_update_post.