# Wordpress: FORM tag doesn't show only at 1st post at Admin Post Lists

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, admin

I'm trying to add the FORM tag in each post at Admin Post Lists but doesn't show only at 1st post.

functions.php code for testing

```
function manage_posts_columns($columns) {
    $columns['status'] = "form test";
    return $columns;
}

function add_column($column_name, $post_id) {
    echo '<form><input type="text" name="mail" size="3" value="" /></form>';
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'manage_posts_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_column', 10, 2 );
```

**1st line source at Admin Post Lists**
There's no form tag.

```
<td class="status column-status" data-colname="form test">
    <input type="text" name="mail" size="3" value="">
</td>
```

**After 2nd line**

```
<td class="status column-status" data-colname="form test">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="mail" size="3" value="">
    </form>
</td>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Comment: why you want form tag here ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.My goal is here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007744/wordpress-how-to-add-publish-draft-button-in-admin-post-lists

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **nest** form tag.

Admin Post Lists is huge form and I added form tag.
That's why it didn't work.